# trying to extract month but got an error integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Data Image]

data.info()
data['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(data['Timestamp'], errors='coerce')

```
import datetime as dt 
#function for month
def get_month(x):
    return dt.datetime(x.year, x.month,1)
#apply the function 
data['get_Timestamp'] = data['Timestamp'].apply(get_month)
data.tail()
```

i want get my timestamp month like 2022-10-01

Comment: What is your value inside `Timestamp` ?

Comment: question subject refers to extract month, but your expected output is YYYY-MM-DD. which of these is correct? Update the question and title accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To extract month usually you can extract via the below snippet

```py
df['get_Timestamp'] = df['ArrivalDate'].dt.month
```

Answer (score 0):

You use **errors='coerce'**. This means that there can be **Nat** values ​​in the dataset. You may be getting an error because the function you are using is trying to convert the Nat value. You can set the function to apply to non-nat values (like if x==pd.isnull). Also you can use this instead of function.

```
data['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(data['Timestamp'], errors='coerce',format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
data['get_Timestamp'] = data['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01')
```