# How to change timestamp from yyyy-dd-mm to yyyy-mm-dd in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Problem image]

```
data['Customer_month'] = data['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01')

data.tail(2)

Timestamp           Name            Customer_month
2022-05-11 21:31:16 Deepak Kumar    2022-05-01
2022-05-11 21:44:55 Subhash chandra 2022-05-01
```

Customer month column should be `2022-11-01 not as 2022-05-1`

my expected dataframe is:

```
Timestamp           Name            Customer_month
2022-05-11 21:31:16 Deepak Kumar    2022-11-01
2022-05-11 21:44:55 Subhash chandra 2022-11-01
```

Comment: Instead of asking a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330058/trying-to-extract-month-but-got-an-error-integer-argument-expected-got-float/74330268#74330268) for the same problem, you can continue with the old question. You can find the solution in my answer to the old question. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Timestamp': ['2022-05-11 21:31:16', '2022-05-11 21:44:55'], 'Name': ['Deepak Kumar', 'Subhash chandra']})
data.Timestamp = data.Timestamp.astype('datetime64')

data['Customer_month'] = data['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%d-01')
print(data)
```

```
            Timestamp             Name Customer_month
0 2022-05-11 21:31:16     Deepak Kumar     2022-11-01
1 2022-05-11 21:44:55  Subhash chandra     2022-11-01
```

Comment: i have 40000 row in a data frame how can i do this for a column ?

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand the question, but this operation will be performed for each row of the data frame, that is, for the entire column